# Android: ANR when creating AdView

Tags: android, admob, adview

For the past week I started getting a lot of ANR reports related to AdMob, AdView creation.
I didn't change anything in my code though.

I'm creating it in my Activity onCreate() method like this:

```
this.adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "axxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Here's the ANR stack I'm getting

```
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:93)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:133)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:261)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:229)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:96)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:52)
at dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>(DexClassLoader.java:57)
at com.google.ads.ag.b(SourceFile:95)
at com.google.ads.ag.a(SourceFile:69)
at com.google.ads.bp.<init>(SourceFile:158)
at com.google.ads.a.w.<init>(SourceFile:266)
at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:508)
at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:94)
```

I tried to create the AdView in a background thread but it seems to work only if created in the UI thread...

Comment: "it seems to work only if created in the UI thread."  then you should use a `Handler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdMob just [released](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/04/google-admob-sdk-v641-released-for.html) v6.4.1 of the Android SDK which should address the ANR issue.

Comment: Hello Eric, I have a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481094/admob-settings-category-crisis
Please help me :(

Comment: This seems not to be fixed. Received the exception today running 6.4.1: 
  at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(Native Method)
  at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:103)
  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:142)
  at dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>(DexClassLoader.java:117)
  at com.google.ads.ak.f(SourceFile:354)
  at com.google.ads.ak.b(SourceFile:95)
  at com.google.ads.ak.a(SourceFile:69)
  at com.google.ads.n.<init>(SourceFile:158)
  at com.google.ads.internal.d.<init>(SourceFile:267)
  at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:508)
  at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>...