# Admob Settings Category Crisis

Tags: android, admob

Hello I have developed an app which is actually **education** based and I want to show admob ad into it. But in admob settings's catgory, there is no `education` section. So I selected `tools` category.

I know `admob` shows relevant ads based on the category of app. And probably that why my app is showing irrelevant ads (not educational). What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Games:Brain & Puzzle` or `Entertainment` as I think they are close enough. Also you major concern should be **App description**. Choose related keywords carefully an let admob showing relevant ads.